# Accessing an array of records trough associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
```

I would like to access questions which a user answered.
I could do it like this:

```
question_ids = []
@user.answers.each do |answer|
  question_ids << answer.question.id
end
Question.where(id: question_ids)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is using `pluck`, to avoid loading all answers objects in memory:

```
Question.where(id: @user.answers.pluck(:question_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins), like this:

```
Question.joins(:answers).where(answers: {user_id: @user.id})
```